# The tag 'ViewModelLocator' does not exist in XML namespace clr-namespace:XXX

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, portable-class-library

I have tried numerous other solutions without any success. I have a class called `ViewModelLocator` which is located in my portable class library. It has a property in it called `ViewModels`, which is of type `Dictionay<K, V>`

Then I have a Windows Phone 8 project that references the portable class library. I added the following to the WP8 app.xaml:

```
<Application
    x:Class="Kaizen.WP8.Test.App"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:phone="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
    xmlns:shell="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Shell;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
    xmlns:test="clr-namespace:Foo.Core.Portable.ViewModel;assembly=Foo.Core.Portable">
    <Application.Resources>

        <test:ViewModelLocator x:Key="ViewModelLocator">
            <test:ViewModelLocator.ViewModels>
                <test:SampleViewModel x:Key="sampleVM"/>
            </test:ViewModelLocator.ViewModels>
        </test:ViewModelLocator>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

When I press F12 on the tags, it navigates to the correct class and or property in my pcl. Which indicates that VS knows about the objects, but when I try and build, I receive the following error:

> The tag 'ViewModelLocator' does not exist in XML namespace
>   'clr-namespace:Foo.Core.Portable.ViewModel;assembly=Foo.Core.Portable'.
>
> The tag 'SampleViewModel' does not exist in XML namespace
>   'clr-namespace:Foo.Core.Portable.ViewModel;assembly=Foo.Core.Portable'.

Could anyone please provide some assistance?

**[Update]**
I reference the pcl version of mvvm light in my pcl project. This is how the `ViewModelLocator` class looks like:

```
public class ViewModelLocator
{
    public dynamic this[string viewModelName]
    {
        get
        {
            if (this.ViewModels.ContainsKey(viewModelName))
            {
                return this.ViewModels[viewModelName];
            }

            else
            {
                return null;
            }
        }
    }

    public Dictionary<string, ViewModelBase> ViewModels { get; set; }

    public ViewModelLocator()
    {
        this.ViewModels = new Dictionary<string, ViewModelBase>();
    }
}
```

My WP8 project also makes use of the mvvm light pcl assemblies. I noticed that, if I make use of the `ViewModelBase` class as the dictionary value, that when I get the errors. It's as there's an issue using the mvvm light pcl between the two projects?!
**[Update]**

Many thanks in advance!!
Kind regards,

Comment: Have you already tried performing a clean before building?

Comment: Are `ViewModelLocator` and `SampleViewModel` declared `public`? Also, is the `Foo.Core.Portable` dll properly referenced by your project? Is the library accessible by your application?

Comment: @Steve - Thanks for the response! Yes I cleaned the project / solution more than once. This did not solve the issue.

Comment: @SuperOli - Yes the class as well as the property is public. Properly referenced by your project? Could you please elaborate? I added the project reference by selecting it from the reference manager (solution tab). Yes - it is accessible it's part of the same solution.

Comment: In NuGet Package Manager make sure MVVMLight, NuGet itself and possibly System.Composition are all up to date. Seems MVVMLight may not be handling this properly at the moment.

Comment: I managed to replicate this issue, simply by renaming the project. No idea on how to fix it though - sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, so I'm not exactly sure what I did wrong in my first attempt, but I recreated the solution and performed more or less the same steps and I didn't receive the error again?! o_O

Comment: I just restarted VS and it went away.

Answer (score 4):

I just had this problem with a .Net 4.5 project.
The solution for me was to change to .Net 4.0, ignore the warnings, and change back to .Net 4.5.
Then the problem was gone.

Don't know if it is a feasible way for others, but it worked for me.

Best regards.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a bit late but I had the same problem with a WPF Desktop app and a control library. The library's default Target Framework was .Net 4 but the Desktop app just after I created in in Visual Studio was by default created with .Net 4 client profile. I changed the Desktop app from .Net 4 client profile to .Net 4 and it worked.

Comment: I've seen issues like that before, defo a valid point and fix for me. Sadly for me this time. Not relevant, I have only got one project.