# Silverlight - ViewModelLocator does not exist in the namespace

Tags: c#, silverlight, mvvm-light

I am quite stuck. I have been trying to get MVVM Light working with Silverlight.
Here is my app.xaml

[image: app.xaml]

So I have referenced the view model and even though the system picks it up correctly I constantly get the error:
The name "ViewModelLocator" does not exist in the namespace "clr-amespace:WebHelpdesk.ViewModel"
Even though it clearly does.
I have reinstalled MVVM Light and been up and down trying to figure it.
Sure it's something simple
Thanks
Scott

Answer (score 1):

Seems it could have been some kind of corruption. I have been adding references and removing quite regularly on this project as it was a testing type situation.
I have rebuilt the project and the references work out the box. No different.
Seems there are many others in the same boat, with no real solution apart from a rebuild. i.e. [The tag 'ViewModelLocator' does not exist in XML namespace clr-namespace:XXX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18257660/the-tag-viewmodellocator-does-not-exist-in-xml-namespace-clr-namespacexxx)
Hope that helps someone out.
Scott

Answer (score 1):

Just had this, definitely some sort of corruption which in my case was oddly enough resolved by deleting and re-adding assemblyinfo.cs (which I did on  whim).

Not even sure if that was the solution but at that point I'd tried everything else.

Comment: I tried this. What I did was remove it (it gets placed in recycling bin), then shut down VS. Cut/Paste it back in to Properties directory, start VS back up. Then add the CS file back... then drag it back in to the properties directory. Clean/rebuild. Seemed to work? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I put mine in a resource dictionary tag, try:

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <cx:ViewModelLocator x:Key="ServiceLocator" />
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

Comment: Tried that also. I actually think there was some kind of corruption. Be comment below. Thanks for your help. Scott

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes, the auto-generated folder ViewModel with files MainViewModel.cs and ViewModelLocator.cs doesn't include in a project by default. In a Solution Explorer enable "Show all files" and include missing folder in a project.

Answer (score 0):

I had my project named XX-Studio the locator space def was xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:XX_Studio.ViewModel" as VS doesn't accept "-" so i renamed the namespace and everything was fine